# AngularJS - JQuery : ngInclude directive - DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

My templates bootstrap contain JS, as they are called JS is not executed, you have an idea please.

This is my Index.html

```
<body ng-app>
    <ng-include src="'sidebar.html'"></ng-include>
    <ng-include src="'navbar.html'"></ng-include>
</body>
```

My navbar.html

```
<header class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="banner">
            <button type="button" id="menu-toggler">
                ...
            </button>
```

in my template library there are - theme.js

```
$("#menu-toggler").click(function (e) {
    $("body").toggleClass("menu");
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
```

when in  Body element there are 'menu' class, CSS show a sidebar

who know why it doesn't show?? ([Demo jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MfHa6/247/))

Answer (score 1):

Do NOT use Angular like you would use jQuery; add `ng-class` to the `<body>`, add `ng-click` to your button and handle the event from Angular:

```
<body ng-class="{'menu': bodyIsMenu} ng-controller="Ctrl">
    ...
    <button ng-click="toggle()">...</button>
    ...
</body>
```

**Note I placed the controller in the body, so as for `toggle()` and `bodyIsMenu` to be in the same scope.** The JS:

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.bodyIsMenu = false;

    $scope.toggle = function() {
        $scope.bodyIsMenu = !$scope.bodyIsMenu;
    };
}
```

Also a very interesting read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background).

Comment: FWIW this example can be more concise, without needing controller code: http://jsfiddle.net/4QFHV/3/